# Как правильно перенести картинки после сжатия webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack4

Имеется такой webpack конфиг(Это общая часть dev и build конфига):

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const ImageminPlugin = require("imagemin-webpack");
const imageminGifsicle = require("imagemin-gifsicle");
const imageminJpegtran = require("imagemin-jpegtran");
const imageminOptipng = require("imagemin-optipng");
const imageminSvgo = require("imagemin-svgo");


const PATHS = {
 src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
 dist: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
 js: 'js/bundle.js',
 css: 'css/style.css',
}

module.exports = {
 externals: {
  paths: PATHS,
 },
 entry: {
  app: PATHS.src,
 },
 output: {
  path: PATHS.dist,
  filename: PATHS.js,
  publicPath: '/',
 },
 module: {
  rules: [
  {
   test: /\.js$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   exclude: '/node_modules/',
  }, 
  {
   test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
   use: [
    {
     loader: 'file-loader',
     options: {
      name: "[name].[ext]"
     }
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   test: /\.less$/,
         use: [
           {
            loader: 'style-loader',
           },
           {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
           }, 
           {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
             sourceMap: true,
            }
           },
           {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
             sourceMap: true,
             config:  {
              path: 'postcss.config.js',
             }
            }
           },
           {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
             sourceMap: true,
            }
           }
         ]
  }]
 },
   plugins: [
     new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
       filename: PATHS.css,
     }),
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: false,
      template: `${PATHS.src}/index.html`,
      filename: 'index.html',
     }),
     new CopyPlugin([
      {
         from: 'src/fonts',
         to: 'fonts',
       },
       {
         from: 'src/img',
         to: 'img'
       }
      ]),
      new ImageminPlugin({
       bail: false,
       imageminOptions: {
        plugins: [
           imageminGifsicle({
              interlaced: true
            }),
            imageminJpegtran({
              progressive: true
            }),
            imageminOptipng({
              optimizationLevel: 5
            }),
            imageminSvgo({
              removeViewBox: true
            })
        ]
       }
      }),
   ],
}
```

Проблема в том, что после сжатия картинки попадают в корневую директорию, т.е. в dist, а надо чтобы они попали в dist/img

Как это можно сделать? С помощью CopyPlugin я пытаюсь перенести изображения в папку dist/img и они переносятся, но только не сжатыми.

Как мне сделать перенос картинок уже после сжатия? И попутный вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы имена файлов оставались такими же, какими они были до сжатия, если да, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить `outputPath` в loader для изображений

```js
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: "[name].[ext]",
      outputPath: 'images/'
    }
  }]
```